# How to enable vt-x in centos on docker on mac os

Tags: macos, docker, centos, virtual-machine

I use official centos image in docker hub.
My machine is mac that support vt-x.
But when I run centos on docker on mac, in centos, it doesn't show vmx in /proc/cpuinfo
I wonder that why guest os(centos) says that doesn't support vm even though my host support.

Is there any way that enable vt-x in centos on docker on my machine?

Comment: There's a hidden intermediate VM that you don't have a lot of direct control over.  Why do you want this?

Comment: @David Maze Thanks. i got it. I was trying to run windows os on docker on mac without virtualbox(or silimar software). I noticed that docker on mac, window use vm actually, when I read a blog post in somewhere, So I thought I can run windows OS on my docker on mac like vmware, virtual box and so on.

Comment: You always need a virtualization layer to run one OS in another.  You also can't run a different OS in Docker (Linux containers on MacOS run via the aforementioned hidden VM) and Docker containers don't run full OS environments in any case.